# How do you change the current path name in real time based on textbox value? react router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, use-context

Suppose there is a route like `<base-url>/search`

the route is defined like

```
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
...
<Router>
  ...
  <Route path="/search/:searchInput">
     <Search />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

There is also a textbox component which uses a `useContext` hook and contextprovider, and `onChange` it keeps the current value of the textbox input which is used by the `<Search/>` component

how do you change the path name in real time to the name of the search input? if the textbox is empty it should default to `<base-url>/search`

for example if you type 'lil' in the textbox, the current route or pathname  will redirect / render simultanously to `<base-url>/search/lil`

if there are multiple words or space in the textbox such as 'lil red', the current path will render immediately to `<base-url>/search/lil%20red`

do i need to use react `<Link/>`?

related thread [How to update the url of a page using an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483582/how-to-update-the-url-of-a-page-using-an-input-field), [react-router - how change the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517129/react-router-how-change-the-url)

**EDIT**

```
import SearchContext from "../Search/context"

const Search = () => {
   const context = useContext(SearchContext)

   // context.searchInput is the value of the textbox provided by context.provider

   useEffect(() => {}, [])

   return (...)
}
export default Search
```

Comment: `Link` is useful when you want to change route based on a user clicking something, if you want to change the route programmatically you can use `useHistory` and then use the history objects `push` or `replace` method to change routes.

Comment: what would be the place to push history and reflect changes on page since i added the search component edit above? Im new to `withRouter`, `useHistory` hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but with the information provided and the time I have to spend on it here is an example of how you could trigger a route update based on your context value.

```
import SearchContext from "../Search/context"
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Search = () => {
    const context = useContext(SearchContext);
    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation();

    // The below use effect will trigger when ever one of the following changes:
    //      - context.searchInput: When ever the current search value updates.
    //      - location.pathname: When ever the current route updates.
    //      - history: This will most likely never change for the lifetime of the app.
    useEffect(() => {
        let basePath = location.pathname;

        // As the available information does not pass a "Base Route" we must calculate it
        // from the available information. The current path may already be a search and
        // duplicate "/search/" appends could be added with out a small amout of pre-processing.
        const searchIndex = basePath.indexOf('/search/');

        // Remove previous "/search/" if found.
        if (searchIndex >= 0) {
            basePath = basePath.substr(0, searchIndex);
        }

        // Calculate new path.
        const newPath = `${basePath}/search/${encodeURI(context.searchInput)}`;

        // Check new path is indeed a new path.
        // This is to deal with the fact that location.pathname is a dependency of the useEffect
        // Changing the route with history.push will update the route causing this useEffect to
        // refire. If we continually push the calculated path onto the history even if it is the
        // same as the current path we would end up with a loop.
        if (newPath !== location.pathname) {
            history.push(newPath);
        }
    }, [context.searchInput, location.pathname, history]);

    return null;
}
```